# How can I replicate a brownout for the purpose of testing

Tags: power, production-testing, brownout

Is there a device or design in which I can place in between the wall outlet and the powered device itself that will cause the powered device to undergo a brownout condition?

Comment: An adjustable bench supply... Unless you want to simulate transient voltages or startup sequencing...

Comment: A Variac (adjustable autotransformer)

Comment: an incandescent light bulb connected in series ...... you can add a switch in parallel with the light bulb to bypass it

Comment: You need to first define what you want to test. Different manufacturers will have different (and sloppy, semi-useless) specifications for their brownout detectors. You need to know something about the brownout situations you ***care*** about. Then I think you should create a simple MCU-controlled power supply that will generate those events for you. Or else buy an arbitrarily programmable (or controllable, say via GPIB or some other interface) power supply. (Not so cheap.) The same thing one does when testing for the human body model and static "zapping" of pins, etc.

Comment: If your device transforms your line voltage to internal voltage, it will be hard to do any controlled "brownout" testing.  You'ld better have direct control over your internal voltage.

Comment: @jsotola I like the simple minimalist solution. This is probably the fastest to implement.Thank you for  your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Variac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer) (brand name that has become generic) — an adjustable autotransformer designed for exactly this.